facebook limit login,can not verify sign
my iOS app upgraded facebook SDK to newest version(17.0), and login throws error

Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token

I used google to an find answer, for v17 I need to implement limit login. I did.
But I find another error:

cannot verify signature

after decode JWT,header message is
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}

The doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/token/ offers public information, the alg is "RS256", it's different with my header message
my code is

I have no idea what to do.

As per the How To Ask guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the formatting tools to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

See also Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
